# Wall light won't work

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

[image: feed from the wall]I have just changed my horrible brass wall lights for a couple of led lights. One works and one doesn't. Tester is showing power is there when I switch it on but still no light. both LEDs work fine any ideas?

Comment: What kind of tester? If you are using a non-contact tester and your hot is connected but not neutral then you will detect power at the fixture but won't have a complete functioning circuit.

Comment: Just a pen voltage tester

Comment: Which is a safe and generally good way to test. However, that will tell you whether the wires have power but won't necessarily tell you if you have a solid connection for hot & neutral to the fixture. Can you post a picture of the wires going to the fixture?

Comment: a) Normally light fixtures would attach to a junction box. Is there one behind the wall? Or are those just wires hanging out? Not clear from the picture. b) Are you in the USA or someplace else? Wire colors, electrical code, etc. vary quite a bit by region.